# POST (or GET) JavaScript (jQuery) variable value to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, post

I want to post/get some variables (values) from JS to example.com/sentdata.php and than use them as php variables.

I was trying to implement some techniques from stack, but I failed.

HTML:

```
<label for="szt-n">Ilość sztuk: </label><input type="number" name="name1" value="0" id="zz" class="quantity s in-sel" /><p id="niebieskie">Cena: <span></span></p>
<label for="szt-r">Ilość sztuk: </label><input type="number" id="xx" name="name2" value="0" class="quantity m in-sel" /><p id="rozowe">Cena: <span></span></p>
 <p id="total">Koszt całkowity: <span></span></p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.quantity').bind('click keyup', function(event) {

           var qs= +$("#zz").val();
           var qm= +$("#xx").val();

        var price = 2;
        var total = (qs + qm) * price;
        var niebieskie = qs * price;
        var rozowe = qm * price;
        total = total + ' PLN';
        niebieskie = niebieskie + ' PLN';
        rozowe = rozowe + ' PLN';

          $("#niebieskie span").html(niebieskie);
          $("#rozowe span").html(rozowe);
          $("#total span").html(total);

    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gigol777/XAfTA/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you use ajax to implement that ?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$.post( "sentdata.php", { name1: $("#zz").val(), name2: $("#xx").val() } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to send data and after processing send response

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.quantity').bind('click keyup', function(event) 
  {
   var qs= +$("#zz").val();
   var qm= +$("#xx").val();
   var price = 2;

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "test.php", //url to send data
       data:{qs:qs,qm:qm,price:price},
       dataType: json,
       success: function(response,textStatus,xhr)
       {
        console.log(response); //check response first from server

        //set value to your required position
          $("#niebieskie span").html(response.niebieskie);
          $("#rozowe span").html(response.rozowe);
          $("#total span").html(response.total);
       },
       error:function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown)
          console.log(textStatus)
     }
    });
  });
});

 //test.php file to get request from js
<?php
    print_r($_REQUEST);//check data sent from js file
    $qs=$_POST['qs'];
    $qm=$_POST['qm'];
    $price=$_POST['total'];

  // further processing on server side
    $total = ($qs + $qm) * $price;
    $niebieskie = $qs * $price;
    $rozowe = $qm * $price;
    $total= $total + ' PLN';
    $niebieskie = $niebieskie + ' PLN';
    $rozowe = $rozowe + ' PLN';
    $response = array('total' => $total, 'niebieskie' => $niebieskie, 'rozowe' => $rozowe);
    echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```